# Постраничное разделение текста

Tags: ios

Пишу читалку. Есть книга в `html`. Разбил ее на главы, как теперь вычислить длину текста, которую может вместить на страницу. Точнее в **UITextView** ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Core Text` есть все, что вам надо. В частности метод `CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange` на основании имеющегося attributed текста вернет сколько символов влезет в заданный фрейм. [Здесь](https://github.com/mayoff/core-text-columns/) отличный пример использования.

На всякий случай копирую весь метод форматирования, если вдруг библиотека пропадет:

```
- (void)layoutColumns {

    CFAttributedStringRef trib = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)_text, NULL);
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(trib);
    CFRelease(trib);

    _boundingBox = CGRectNull;
    _columnFrames = CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
    NSUInteger columnIndex = 0;
    NSUInteger startIndex = 0;
    NSUInteger endIndex = _text.length;
    while (startIndex < endIndex) {
        _boundingBox = CGRectUnion(_boundingBox, [self borderRectForColumnIndex:columnIndex]);
        CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect([self contentRectForColumnIndex:columnIndex], NULL);
        CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(startIndex, 0), path, NULL);
        CGPathRelease(path);
        CFArrayAppendValue(_columnFrames, frame);
        ++columnIndex;
        CFRange frameRange = CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange(frame);
        CFRelease(frame);
        if (frameRange.length == 0) {
            NSLog(@"error: column size is too small to fit character at index %u", startIndex);
            break;
        }
        startIndex += frameRange.length;
    }

    CFRelease(framesetter);
}
```

Comment: ok, very gooood ))